# Deleting file from Firebase storage causes crash

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to delete user's account but before deleting account I try to delete data that belongs to user. It does it, however after deleting all the data and user the app crashes and I can't see the problem.

I tried the "Zombie" to see why I get error and I tried breakpoint and only thing I could find is this:

> 2016-10-22 15:31:53.080008 App[7521:1721097] [Common] _BSMachError:
>   port 69d3; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert
>   COPY_SEND"
>
> _BSMachError: port 69d3; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"2016-10-22 15:31:53.083114 App[7521:1721097] [Common]

All my breakpoints passed!

This is the code part that crashes the appp:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("users/\(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid)").delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Swift 3** i dont think there is any function *delete()* in **FIRStorage** class , Try :-

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("users/\(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid)").delete(completion: {(err) in

    print(err?.localizedDescription)
    })
```

For **Swift 2**

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("users/\(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid)").deleteWithCompletion({(err) in

    print(err?.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Comment: I think there is because it deletes the file :D And your given code should just point to that not delete.

Comment: Ohh.. I am so stupid.. It has to be like this: `// Delete the file
desertRef.deleteWithCompletion { (error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // File deleted successfully
  }
}`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo